# How to use BufferedReader to get an interger

Tags: java, console, int

I'm writing a little program for myself and I bump into a problem.

I want to be able to type a number into the console, and extract the number for a variable.
Until this point I got it.

```
int aNumber = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Except I want to get an error when there is something entered into the console that's not a number.

Something like this but working ofcourse:

```
void Test() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            aNumber = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (aNumber >= 1) {
            System.out.println("Hurray you enterd a number! It is " + aNumber + ".");
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Something went wrong. Please try again.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

If you enter a number it works fine. But I want to be able to enter texts and getting an error to try again.

## Example if you type in the console:

*1*

Answer:

**Hurray you enterd a number! It is 1.**

=====

*2564*

Answer:

**Hurray you enterd a number! It is 2564.**

=====

*eaf123*

Answer:

**Error: Something went wrong. Please try again.**

=====

Thanks for everyone trying to help.

Lars Meeuwsen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work. I hope you understand the solution. `Integer.parseInt()` throws `NumberFormatException` if parse fails.

```
void test() {
            while (true) {
                int aNumber;
                try {
                    aNumber = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                    System.out.println("Hurray you enterd a number! It is " + aNumber + ".");
                    return;
                } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error: Something went wrong. Please try again.\n");

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because entering a string or any other type besides `int`, generates a `NumberFormatException` and you are not catching it.

The if statement is unnecessary since the catch block will be executed only if text  is given. Exception will be thrown at conversion so the line below will not execute.

Please check this code

```
void Test() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            aNumber = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            System.out.println("Hurray you enterd a number! It is " + aNumber + ".");
            return;
        } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error: Something went wrong. Please try again.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest thing you could do is to catch the `NumberFormatException` and then print the message you want.

See below for a working example:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ReadNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int aNumber = 0;

        while (true) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            try {
                aNumber = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("That wasn't a number.");
                continue;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (aNumber >= 1) {
                System.out.println("Hurray you entered a number! It is " + aNumber + ".");
                continue;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: Something went wrong. Please try again.\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```